# adding custom row with data in wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not able to add a new row in wp_usermeta of WordPress database.
I have this code in my plugin,  I access the database and tried to store the data in the form in the admin dashboard. 
I have the following code:

```
function kpam_application_management_Users()
{
        global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users");
    echo '

<h2>Applicants</h2>
<table style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Progress</th>

  </tr>';
    foreach( $results as $user_data) {
        echo "<tr>
    <td>$user_data->ID</td>
    <td>$user_data->user_nicename</td>
    <td>$user_data->user_email</td>
    <form method=POST action=>
    <td><input type=number name=progressz>
<button id=btnConfirm type=submit name=button >Update</button>
    </td>
    </form>

  </tr>";
}
    echo '</table> <br><br>';

if ( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ){
         global $wpdb;
         $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'usermeta';

        $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array(
            'user_id' => 1,
            'meta_key' => 'progress',
            'meta_value' => $_POST['progressz']), 

            array( '%s','%s','%s') 

       );


    }
}
```

Comment: There are no quotes surrounding your attribute declarations.

Comment: i tried with that but it still does not works.

Comment: Your closing form tag is incorrect. Should be: `</form>`. And how are you sending the form data to your php file?

Comment: even that does not work for me

Comment: And how are you sending the form data to your php file? Please show more, relevant code.

Comment: actually id did it in the plugin the code is edited you can see now

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

First, why are you running `$wpdb` queries for this instead of using WordPress' helper functions like [`get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) or the [`WP_User_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) class, and [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/) function to store the submitted information?

Second, you should make sure your code is properly formatted in a standard syntax to be easier to update and maintain (and not echo giant blocks of HTML like that) - future you thanks you!

Third are you just running the `if ( isset( $_POST['button'] ) ){` code right there? You should probably hook it somewhere, and make use of one of [WordPress' many `nonce`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) functions instead of relying on an arbitrary commonly named button.

That said, I've cleaned it up a bit and used the helper function, but something like this should get you closer to what you're looking for:

```
function kpam_application_management_users(){ ?>
    <h2>Applicants</h2>
    <table style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $users = get_users();

            foreach( $users as $user ){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $user->ID; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user->user_nicename; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $user->user_email; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>" />
                            <input type="number" name="progressz" placeholder="<?php echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'progressz', true ); ?>" />
                            <button id="btnConfirm" type="submit" name="progressz-submit">Update</button>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            <?php }
        ?>
    </table>
<?php }

if( isset( $_POST['progressz-submit'] ) ){
    update_user_meta( $_POST['user_id'], 'progressz', $_POST['progressz'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, it's still not working for me.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump( $_POST );` and show the results?

Comment: array(3) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["progressz"]=> string(1) "4" ["progressz-submit"]=> string(0) "" }

THis is the results

Comment: **oof** - I apologize, in the code I used [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) instead of `update_user_meta()`. I've changed that -

Comment: its showing Critical error on change from update_post_meta() to update_user_meta().

Comment: What's the error? Looks like when I rewrote it I change `kpam_application_management_users` to lowercase, make sure it's lowercase when you're calling it

Comment: ```function kpam_application_manager(){
  add_submenu_page('kpam-application','PROGRESS', 'Progress','manage_options', "kpam-Progress", 'kpam_application_management_progress');


}
add_action('admin_menu','kpam_application_manager');```